# Associating a variable to a color palette?

Tags: r, colors, plot

I am working with some very simple gaze tracking data, consisting in a 3 vars matrix : **X** & **Y** coordinates and **Fixation** time in seconds.

I would like to plot my **X**, **Y** coordinates in a simple scatterplot, where the color of the points would be a function of the **Fixation** variable. How would you link a variable's values to the colors of a palette going from green to red automatically ? My **Fixation** values go from 0 to 1.3364.

The purpose is to make the long fixation points red and those with short fixation time green.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the section on [asking for code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). A quick google search will find many examples that you will be able to modify and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @mnel's comment but don't seem to find any question on SO answering even marginally your question. Basically you need to use `cut`. Let's say your limit between a long and a short fixation time is 0.5 then:

```
plot(x, y, col=c("green","red")[cut(z, c(0,0.5,1.5))])
```

With a made-up dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=runif(10, 0, 1.3364))
with(dat, plot(x, y, col=c("green","red")[cut(z, c(0,0.5,1.5))]))
```

If you need a continuous color palette, you need to use that in combination with `colorRampPalette`:

```
gr <- colorRampPalette(c("green","red"))
with(dat, plot(x, y, col=gr(30)[cut(z, seq(0,1.5,length.out=30))]))
```

Comment: Problem: impossible to use the jpeg() or pdf() function to save the plot. Would you know why ? Thanks.

Comment: preceeding this code with a call to `jpeg()` and following the code with `dev.off()` works very well, as with any other plot. There is nothing specific about this one, it's actually a rather basic plot.